# parentheses error in flutter tired to solve it myself and researched it but it was no use

Tags: flutter, dart

ı am having a problem with the parentheses ı added a photo of where it gives the error and the error code itself[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxhmI.png) [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqEXC.png)

ı was just trying to convert string to int and assigning the values for the later part of the project

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code image

Answer (score 0):

The if condition will take a boolean, and dont use end line. The format will be

```dart
if( slot1==true ){ ....}
```

Or just do

```dart
if(slot1){ ....}
```

Same goes for `else if(slot2){...}`

Answer (score 0):

As I've seen you're setting your if else conditions with a semi-colon `;`, and this is wrong, you need to remove them, in addition, that the equality condition is made with double `==`

```
if(1 + 1 == 2;) // wrong
if(1 + 1 = 2) // wrong
if(1 + 1 = 2;) // wrong
if(1 + 1 == 2) // right
```

you need to correct it in all your `if else` statements.

in your case, your `if` conditions should be like this:

```
if(slot1 == true) // right
```

This should fix your issue.

**Optional recommendation:**

However, for boolean have which are `true`, consider using them directly without specifying that they should equal `true` with a double `==` because they are already `true` in the first place.

```
if(slot1) // right also
```